# Is this theorem Correct.

Tags: pythagorean-triples

If it is, is it trivial?

```
                                          **Theorem**
```

There does not exist a pythagorean triple $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$  $\{a,b,c \in \Bbb N\}$
where $b \ge a$ and $a|b$

```
                                          **PROOF**
```

Suppose $\exists$  a constant k {$k | k \ge 1, k \in \Bbb N$} and $k \cdot a$ forms a pythagorean triple with a.

I.e $a^2 + (k \cdot a)^2 = c^2$

$a^2 + k^2 \cdot a^2 =c^2 $

$a^2(k^2 + 1) = c^2$

$c = \sqrt{a^2(k^2 + 1)}$

$c = a \sqrt{k^2 + 1} $

$ \exists $ $ k:  \sqrt{k^2 + 1} \in \Bbb Q$

However $\forall$ $ a \in \Bbb N$, $ a \ge 1$ $ \sqrt{a^2 + 1} \notin \Bbb Q$*

Where $ \Bbb Q$ is the set of rational numbers.

*: The proof of this theorem is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I hope b|a reads a is a factor of b?

Comment: It is usually read $b$ divides $a$. Your proof is correct otherwise (once you change the theorem's hypothesis)

Comment: So I should change it to a|b ?

Comment: What I meant in english is this: $ b \ge a $ and a is a factor of b.

Comment: Then it should be $a|b$ indeed.

Comment: The proof shows only that $\sqrt{k^2+1}$ cannot be $c/a$ (rational). How did you deduce that it would have to be natural number? For example you can have $1 = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I said $k: k \ge 1$ I don't think $\exists$ $k \in \Bbb N$ $k: (\sqrt{k^2 +1} ) \in \Bbb N$ I have an informal proof, but I'm not sure how rigorous it is, which is why I left it as an exercise to the reader. I am not following you.

Comment: Two comments: If $a|b$ then $b \ge a$. There have been a number of proofs here showing that the square root of every non-square integer is irrational.

Comment: My point is that you have shown that $c = a \sqrt{k^2 + 1} $, and then somehow from that you concluded that $\sqrt{k^2+1}$ must be $\in \Bbb N$, which does not follow. It just has to be rational, and as marty mentions, there are proofs for that not being possible.

Comment: Oh. I get what you're saying now. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @marty cohen, we have $\sqrt{K^2 + 1}$ won't you have to prove that this is first a non-square integer. I.e $\forall$ $a \in \Bbb N$ $a^2 + 1$ is \not\eq b^2

Comment: $\neq b^2$ $ b: b \in \Bbb N$

Comment: No. $k^2+1$ is a non-square integer because the next square is $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\quad A=m^2-n^2\quad B=2mn\quad \text{then}  \quad \frac{B}{A}=\frac{2mn}{(m+n)(m-n)}$$
By inspection, we can see that $\frac{B}{A}\in\mathbb{Q}$ but is never an integer or vice versa.